Shifter problem
i just repair my FD. So I removed the cable from the bolt. After I finished adjusting the FD I didn't tighten the bolt and cable properly so the cable came loose. After I reattached the cable. The shifter didn't work like usual.When I pull cable its tighten but only little bit. Anyone know how to fix this?

You can preload the cable before tightening the locknut to get all the slack out. It helps if you have 3 arms but 2 will suffice.

Shift to smallest ring.
Adjust the barrel adjuster to its shortest setting.
By hand, move the derailleur a Goldilocks amount towards the big ring. Hold it there.
Pull out any slack in the cable by hand or gently with pliers to avoid crimping the cable.
Lock the cable nut.
Release the derailleur. It should return to the low stop setting if you weren’t too enthusiastic about moving it at step 3.

With any luck the cable will have no slack in it and a shift will take you to the next biggest ring. If you are close on the slack side you can use the barrel adjuster to finish up.

Often, you have to pull the cable with some force when attaching it, e.g., with a pair of pliers. It helps to loosen the barrel adjuster to be able to tighten the cable with it as well. If you are attaching the cable correctly, these steps should suffice, but it sometimes takes several tries to get the cable tight in the right amount.
